# Adding sub keys to a dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a initial dictionary that looks something like this:

```
tree_data = {
    "name": "Creation",
    "children": [],
};
```

I then have a defaultdict collection of items like this:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'2023-09-19 20:02:26.389448': ['title',
              'description',
              'leave type'],
             '2023-09-20 20:02:26.389448': ['title',
              'description',
              'leave type'],
             '2023-09-21 20:02:26.389448': ['approval status', 'notes']})
```

Now for every item in the defaultdict, I want to append it to the `tree_data` dictionary such that for every value in the defaultdict, a `children` key is added to `tree_data`.

I want my final output to look like this:

```
{'name': 'Creation',
 'children': [{'name': 'Update title, description, leave type on 2023-09-19',
   'children': [{'name': 'Update title, description, leave type on 2023-09-19',
     'children': [{'name': 'Update title, description, leave type on 2023-09-19'}]}]}]}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I think they way to go about this is a recursive solution but I am struggling to do so, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I am struggling"*: please show your code so we can see what you are struggling with.